# Move too long equation to center and expand the width of text in LaTeX?

Tags: equations, align, width

I make a formula that is too long so it shows not centred. I hope to move it to the centre and expand the text width only for this formula so after this formula, I hope the width of text return to default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{align}
      \label{eq:MgSO4}
     \left( \ce{MgSO4}\right)&=-\frac{10^{\text{pH}+\frac{47580 t^2+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{29441213}{5000000}}}
      {
        \splitfrac{-10^{\frac{16393 t^2}{25000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{47580 t^2+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{89554959 t}{500000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{340471}{5 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}}{-10^{\text{pH}+\frac{58880041}{10000000}} 
        \left(10^{\text{pH}}+10^{\frac{47580 t^2+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}\right)}}\\
      \label{eq:CaSO4}
      \left(\ce{CaSO4}\right)&=-\frac{10^{\frac{16393 t^2}{25000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{47580 t^2+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{89554959 t}{500000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{340471}{5 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}}
      {
        \splitfrac{-10^{\frac{16393 t^2}{25000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{47580 t^2+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{89554959 t}{500000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{340471}{5 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}}{-10^{\text{pH}+\frac{58880041}{10000000}} 
        \left(10^{\text{pH}}+10^{\frac{47580 t^2+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}\right)}}\\
      \label{eq:CaMg(CO3)2}
      \left(\ce{CaMg(CO3)2}\right)&=-\frac{10^{2 \text{pH}+\frac{58880041}{10000000}}}
      {
        \splitfrac{-10^{\frac{16393 t^2}{25000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{47580 t^2+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{89554959 t}{500000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{340471}{5 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}}{-10^{\text{pH}+\frac{58880041}{10000000}} 
        \left(10^{\text{pH}}+10^{\frac{47580 t^2+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}\right)}}   
   \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]
As the denominator has been split into two parts, is there a way to add background to the denominator so that the reader knows those two parts should be read together?

Comment: Your example produces `! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \UseTblrLibrary`

Comment: the massive ugly denominator appears to be the same in all cases, why repeat it?, define it to be X then just use X in each case and it will be far more readable and easily fit.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Hello, I modified it. Just move it to center and add expand the width of text which will solve these problem.

Comment: you could use adjustwidth but really I would use a different layout if you expect people to read it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I must use the template from my school. I hope only modify this formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit of a hack, of course, stylistically speaking, but this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}  % throws an error
\usepackage{chngpage}
\begin{document}
%\centering  % why is this here?
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.5cm}{-2.5cm}  
\begin{align}
      \label{eq:MgSO4}
     \left( \ce{MgSO4}\right)&=-\frac{10^{\text{pH}+\frac{47580 t^2+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{29441213}{5000000}}}
      {
        \splitfrac{-10^{\frac{16393 t^2}{25000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{47580 t^2+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{89554959 t}{500000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{340471}{5 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}}{-10^{\text{pH}+\frac{58880041}{10000000}} 
        \left(10^{\text{pH}}+10^{\frac{47580 t^2+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}\right)}}\\
      \label{eq:CaSO4}
      \left(\ce{CaSO4}\right)&=-\frac{10^{\frac{16393 t^2}{25000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{47580 t^2+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{89554959 t}{500000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{340471}{5 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}}
      {
        \splitfrac{-10^{\frac{16393 t^2}{25000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{47580 t^2+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{89554959 t}{500000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{340471}{5 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}}{-10^{\text{pH}+\frac{58880041}{10000000}} 
        \left(10^{\text{pH}}+10^{\frac{47580 t^2+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}\right)}}\\
      \label{eq:CaMg(CO3)2}
      \left(\ce{CaMg(CO3)2}\right)&=-\frac{10^{2 \text{pH}+\frac{58880041}{10000000}}}
      {
        \splitfrac{-10^{\frac{16393 t^2}{25000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{47580 t^2+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{89554959 t}{500000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{340471}{5 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}}{-10^{\text{pH}+\frac{58880041}{10000000}} 
        \left(10^{\text{pH}}+10^{\frac{47580 t^2+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}\right)}}   
   \end{align}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

This uses package `chngpage` with the `adjustwidth` environment.

Comment: ah I was just suggesting the same in a comment as you posted this, +1 :-)

Comment: May you tell me how to add gray background of denominator?

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution, which combines loading `geometry`, to have more decent margins, the `fleqn` environment and medium-sized fractions from `nccmath`, and `\mathrlap` from `mathtools`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
    \usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{fleqn}
    \begin{align}
          \label{eq:MgSO4}
         \left( \ce{MgSO4}\right)&=-\mathrlap{\mfrac{10^{\text{pH}+\frac{47580 t²+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{29441213}{5000000}}}
          {
            \splitfrac{-10^{\frac{16393 t²}{25000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{47580 t²+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{89554959 t}{500000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{340471}{5 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}}{-10^{\text{pH}+\frac{58880041}{10000000}}
            \left(10^{\text{pH}}+10^{\frac{47580 t²+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}\right)}}}\\
          \label{eq:CaSO4}
          \left(\ce{CaSO4}\right)&=-\mathrlap{\mfrac{10^{\frac{16393 t²}{25000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{47580 t²+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{89554959 t}{500000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{340471}{5 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}}
          {
            \splitfrac{-10^{\frac{16393 t²}{25000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{47580 t²+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{89554959 t}{500000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{340471}{5 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}}{-10^{\text{pH}+\frac{58880041}{10000000}}
            \left(10^{\text{pH}}+10^{\frac{47580 t²+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}\right)}}}\\
          \label{eq:CaMg(CO3)2}
          \left(\ce{CaMg(CO3)2}\right)&=-\mathrlap{\mfrac{10^{2 \text{pH}+\frac{58880041}{10000000}}}
          {
            \splitfrac{-10^{\frac{16393 t²}{25000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{47580 t²+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{89554959 t}{500000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{340471}{5 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}}{-10^{\text{pH}+\frac{58880041}{10000000}}
            \left(10^{\text{pH}}+10^{\frac{47580 t²+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20 t+5463)}+\frac{477}{2000000}}\right)}}}
       \end{align}
    \end{fleqn}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Will `geometry` change other parts' margin in this file?

Comment: @Y.zeng:  Yes, it changes margins for the whole document. You also may specify which margins you want through optional arguments. From my my point of view, it can be problematic only if you use marginal notes. You also can change margins only for a part of the document with the `\newgeometry` command.

Comment: How about trying this package `chngpage`?

Answer (score 4):

Increasing the width of the text block may help slightly. However, I think it's preferable to focus on identifying common "blocks" or "chunks" in the numerator and denominator terms of the three equations. For instance, one may notice not only that all three denominators are the same, but that the numerator of the fraction in the second equation occurs in all three big denominators. Hence, the RHS of the second equation might be written as `\frac{U}{U+V}`. After some more gathering of common terms, one arrives at the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ten}{ten}
\newcommand\pH{\mathrm{pH}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Put $\ten(x)\equiv 10^{x}$. Then
\begin{align}
( \ce{MgSO4})    &= A/D \label{eq:MgSO4} \\
(\ce{CaSO4})     &= B/D \label{eq:CaSO4} \\
(\ce{CaMg(CO3)2})&= C/D \label{eq:CaMg(CO3)2}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align*}
A&=\ten(\pH+H+N) \\
B&=\ten(G+H+J+K+L) \\
C&=\ten(2\pH+M) \\
D&=B + \ten(\pH+M) [\ten(\pH)+\ten(H+L)] \\
\shortintertext{and}
G&= \frac{16393 t^2}{25000 (20t+5463)} \\[\jot]
H&= \frac{47580 t^2+12996477 t+5804780000}{100000 (20t+5463)} \\[\jot]
J&= \frac{89554959 t}{500000 (20t+5463)} \\[\jot]
K&= \frac{340471}{5 (20t+5463)} \\[\jot]
L&= \frac{477}{2000000} \\[\jot]
M&= \frac{58880041}{10000000} \\[\jot]
N&= \frac{29441213}{5000000} \,.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, now equation finally become legible ...

Comment: @Zarko - Thanks!

Comment: It is a good idea.